# Creating Azure Blob using Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure

I wan't to create a blob using javascript and a SharedAccessSignature. All javascript files are deployed in the BlobStorage, where i want to upload my blob, so I hope Same Site Origin should be no problem. The Server sends the client the SharedAccessSignature and the client uploads the file/data into the blob storage.

Is this possible?

If yes: Is there a javascript library for blob handling? (I've found this [library](http://azureblobstoragejs.codeplex.com/releases/view/32114), but it doesn't support PutBlob operations)

If no: Is the best alternative approach, to implement the upload functionality in the according ASP.Net site and let javascript call some provided method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a node.js module for access to Azure storage. You could use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to use it client side. Of course, there is always some risk in putting your Access Keys in javascript where they could be read. Who knows what your storage account could be serving up.

Comment: The node module is also on github so you can see what javascript code is packaged up for accessing your storage account